# why does git status suggest using git checkout with dashes before filenames?

Tags: git

Best explained with an example:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   README

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   CONTRIBUTING.md
```

This may be a minor detail, but why write `git checkout -- <file>` when `git checkout <file>` works? I tested and it also works with the dashes, but I can't figure out what they are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git checkout filename` only works when you don't have a branch named `filename`.  :D

The `--` disambiguates.  If you want to check out a branch named `foo`:

```
> git checkout foo
Switched to branch 'foo'
```

If you want to check out a filename named `foo` in the current branch:

```
> git branch
  foo
* master
> git checkout -- foo
> cat foo
This is file `foo` in the `master` branch.
```

And if you want to check out a filename named `foo` as it exists in the branch `foo`:

```
> git branch
  foo
* master
> git checkout foo -- foo
> cat foo
This is file `foo` in the `foo` branch.
```

Answer (score 2):

`--` is a syntax borrowed from bash. Quotation from manpage of bash:

> --
>   A -- signals the end of options and disables further option processing.
>   Any arguments after the -- are treated as filenames and arguments. 
>   An argument of - is equivalent  to --.

Comment: Not from bash but from GNU options standard.

Comment: @phd, `--`, used as an options delimiter, has  a long history before GNU, please refer to this 
 question. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147143/when-and-how-was-the-double-dash-introduced-as-an-end-of-options-delimiter

Comment: Then it's even more "not from bash".

Comment: @phd, Yes, I found the explanation to `--` in manpage of bash  firstly, but when I explored more, I realized that It has a much longer history.